# How can I identify a quarter or half wave plate from a used/modified Strainoptics polarimeter?

Tags: optics, polarization, elasticity, stress-strain, glass

I'm a glassblower and I need to test glass formulas for compatibility. I'd like to use a polarimeter as it allows not only the detection of strain, but also informs if a glass needs to be softer or harder. I purchased a Strainoptics A100 analyzer (Senarmont polarimeter) from a surplus supplier overseas. When it arrived, I tested it over a plane polarized light source and found no darkfield could be achieved no matter the rotation of the analyzer. I removed the 2 lenses from the metal frame and found that they both had observable polarization when viewed with a polariscope (between polarized filters). I sent it to Strainoptics and they confirmed that the lenses had been replaced at some point in a manner that did not allow for polarimeter measurement. However, they did not tell me what the lenses are QWP?, HWP? I spoke to the technician working on the unit and described the lenses as thick and thin. When I said "thick" she said that was the 1/2 wave plate. I didn't know these had 1/2 wave plates.

[image: From the Strainoptics user manual]

I would like to figure out what the analyzer needs to get working again. If I just need one lens I'd like to know and fix the problem. Strainoptics doesn't want to figure it out and just sent me the bill for a new one. My problems are 2-fold: I don't know what is normally found in a Senarmont analyzer ring and I don't know what mine has. It was intended to be used as shown with a tripod mount and a polarized light source. Mine does not have circular polarization options (Tardy method).[image: From Strainoptics website. Shows how the analyzer and illuminator are used in the field]

This diagram shows a Full Wave tint plate in use with a 1/4 wave plate/analyzer from a competitor in China. I am wondering if this is the best description of what is needed. Hoping someone is familiar with the ins and outs of these devices and may have advice for getting mine working that doesn't involve the $1500 price tag Strainoptics gave me. Thanks.

[image: From the website of PTC in China which also makes Polarimeters]